# groupby in pandas and exclude grouper column from output DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to groupby a pandas df so that it keeps the key as index but it doesn't include the key in each group.

Here is an example of what I mean.

1. the original dataframe

   `ungrouped_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','A','B','C','C','C'], 'col2':[8,5,1,4,1,2], 'col3':[7,4,2,1,2,1],'col4':[1,8,0,2,0,0]})`

out:

```
| index | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
|-------|------|------|------|------|
| 1     |    A |    8 |    7 |    1 |
| 2     |    A |    5 |    4 |    8 |
| 3     |    B |    1 |    2 |    0 |
| 4     |    C |    4 |    1 |    2 |
| 5     |    C |    1 |    2 |    0 |
| 6     |    C |    2 |    1 |    0 |
```

2. now, I would like to create a numpy array from the grouped dataframe

   `grouped_df = ungrouped_df.groupby(by='col1', group_keys=False).apply(np.asarray)`

This is what I get

```
| index | col1                                      | 
|-------|-------------------------------------------|
| A     | [[A, 8, 7, 1],[A, 5, 4, 8],[A, 8, 7, 1]]  |
| B     | [[B, 1, 2, 0]]                            |
| C     | [[C, 4, 1, 2], [C, 1, 2, 0], [C, 2, 1, 0]]|
```

3. This is what I'd like to get instead

out:

```
| index | col1                             | 
|-------|----------------------------------|
| A     | [[8, 7, 1],[5, 4, 8],[8, 7, 1]]  |
| B     | [[1, 2, 0]]                      |
| C     | [[4, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0]]|
```

I can use some advice here because I am a bit lost. I thought that "group_keys=False" would do the trick but it doesn't. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I generally don't recommend storing lists in columns, but the most obvious way to fix this is to ensure the unwanted column is not being grouped on.

You can specify that either by

1. setting "col1" as the index before grouping, or
2. drop "col1" before grouping, or
3. selecting the columns you DO want to group

---

```
df.set_index('col1').groupby(level=0).apply(np.array)

col1
A               [[8, 7, 1], [5, 4, 8]]
B                          [[1, 2, 0]]
C    [[4, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0]]
```

OR,

```
df.drop('col1', 1).groupby(df['col1']).apply(np.array)

col1
A               [[8, 7, 1], [5, 4, 8]]
B                          [[1, 2, 0]]
C    [[4, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0]]
```

OR,

```
(df.groupby('col1')[df.columns.difference(['col1'])]
   .apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist()))

col1
A               [[8, 7, 1], [5, 4, 8]]
B                          [[1, 2, 0]]
C    [[4, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0]]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi, the first and second option are great for my case. it was that easy! thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `pd.Series.groupby`

```
df = df.drop('col1',1).agg(list,1).groupby(df.col1).agg(list).reset_index(name='out')
```

...

```
df
  col1                                out
0    A             [[8, 7, 1], [5, 4, 8]]
1    B                        [[1, 2, 0]]
2    C  [[4, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Hmm, output doesn't seem right, only integers should be present in the result. Can you take a look? :-)